# WifiManager takes long time to connect a network in android

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am trying to connect an open `Wifi network` using the following code:

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int netid = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
if(netid != -1){
   wifiManager.enableNetwork(netid,true);
}
```

Wifi connects `100%` times using above code but takes long time to connect. `enableNetwork` method returns `true` immediately and after `20-40 seconds` wifi becomes connected. I also tried `wifimanager.reconnct()` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

this method connects to your wifi - networkSSID -is your network ssid and networPass is your network password

```
 private void connect(String networkSSID ,String  networkPass ) 
{


        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";


       if (scanResult.capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
            conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        }

        else if (scanResult.capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
            conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        }

        else
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);


        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);


        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```